# How can I update my javascript variable values?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using some javascript to draw a svg path using divs as endpoints.

```
var thepath = $('#thepath');

var startx1 = $('#box2').position().left;
var starty1 = $('#box2').position().top;
var realDealPath = 'M ' + startx1 + ',' + starty1;


var startx2 = $('#box3').position().left;
var starty2 = $('#box3').position().top;

realDealPath += 'L' + (startx2+50) + ',' + starty2;

var startx3 = $('#box6').position().left;
var starty3 = $('#box6').position().top;

realDealPath += 'L' + startx3 + ',' + starty3;

thepath.attr('d', realDealPath);
```

It works great! But when I scale the browser, the svg path doesn't adjust to the new div positions. Is there a way to keep these values updated?

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: You can update them handling the `resize` event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much!